# Return a bitmap in function

Tags: bitmap, c++-cli

This is my first post here, so I apologize in advance if I mess up something :)
I'm using VS2010, and I'm newbie in C++ programming.

I have a function and trying to return a Bitmap, but it drops error:

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Bitmap'
```

My function is:

```
System::Drawing::Bitmap^ Card::DisplayCard(){
   System::Drawing::Bitmap^ Image = gcnew Bitmap("C:\\MySoftware\\images\\Card.png");
return Image; }
```

I would like to use this function to return a Bitmap and I can use that in a PictureBox.

Thank you very much !

Comment: `Bitmap^` what is the `^` used for?

Comment: This is C++.net; the ^ indicates a managed .NET reference object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the fully-qualified type name in the constructor. Write

```
... = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(...);
```

Alternatively, import the Bitmap name to avoid needing the fully-qualified name, by adding

```
using System::Drawing::Bitmap;
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Yes with using it's more simple :)